# Dom parsing in Android

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing

If I parse the tag that contains `<p>Some Text</p>` tag, I get a null pointer exception.

My RSS feed is as follows:

```
<quaddeals_conditions><p>Limit one QuadDeal</p></quaddeals_conditions>
```

My code is:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("quaddeals_conditions")) {
    property.normalize();
    conditions = property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();   
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Logcat Message and some detail explanation of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an element

inside an element .

Therefore retrieve all quaddeals and then iterate each one and retrieve from it the p element:

```
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(this.inputStream);
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();

// snip

NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName("quaddeals_conditions");
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node item = items.item(i);
            NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                Node property = properties.item(j);
                String name = property.getNodeName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                    property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); // Your paragraph data
                }
            }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I always run into this when parsing dom and think you have the right approach. He may need to drop down several levels but I believe you've shown him the light ;)

Comment: Paragraph itself is an element (inside the quaddeals element).
You should really check if your name variable is not null (with debugger, Log output)
I also don't understand why you get NullPointer in conjunction with println method. Can you post the affected code line? Maybe the exception occurs somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

is "name" not NULL? I dont see you check for that.
It's good coding practice to compare the other way if possible:

`if ("quaddeals_conditions".equalsIgnoreCase(name))`...

So even if "name" is NULL, you don't get a NullPointerException.
Always check for not null before accessing some object member.

Comment: 01-24 20:04:24.858: VERBOSE/Exception ee(447): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: You will get "println needs a message" Error, if you `Log.x()` something which is NOT a String. Always add `.toString()` if the Object is the only parameter:
`Log.d(TAG,myNode)` will fail, 
`Log.d(TAG,myNode.toString())` works, 
`Log.d(TAG,"Here: "+myNode)` works too, because it's clear you are building a String.
So, the error you got is from logging ;)